# OpenOffice / LibreOffice ugly font rendering

Tags: fonts, openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'm using Calc to generate some graphs of data I have collected. But somehow the font looks increadibly ugly in all of LibreOffice. I'm using Noto Sans CJK JP Light in this chart but pretty much every Japanese font I've tried looks ugly.

Is there any way to fix this or do I have to make the graphs on my own in Illustrator?

The problem exists in both OpenOffice and LibreOffice in their most recent version.

[image: Table from Calc]

Comment: Are you using KDE?

Comment: @Aleksandar Pavić This was on Windows 10.

Comment: Well, what helped on KDE and Linux was setting font anti aliasing, and forcing DPI.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following helped.

You may change Compatibility setting of the SOFFICE.exe file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe Right click ->
>   Properties -> Change high DPI settings -> High DPI scaling override -
>   check "Override high DPI scaling bahvior. Application"

Windows 7/8

OpenOffice forum:

> by BurleighBill » Mon Nov 25, 2013 7:59 am  Right click the file,
>   choose Properties, select the Compatibility tab, and check the box to
>   "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings." Now Open Office is
>   super crisp!